How to configure WiFi adapter to use a static IP address?
For reasons, I need to configure the WiFi adapter on a client machine to use a static IP address (IPv4 only).
I found a bunch of different instruction on how to do this online, but they're all slightly different.  I gave it a shot by editing the existing .yaml file in /etc/netplan that was automagically created for me when I installed Ubuntu 24, but that didn't work.  Below is the original .yaml file followed by my edited version.  WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?
Original auto-generated .yaml file:
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-322035e3-8bac-4b5e-8a0b-d9ff4b11629d:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "wlx8416f90c89ec"
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "Enigma_5G":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: "REDACTED"
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "322035e3-8bac-4b5e-8a0b-d9ff4b11629d"
            name: "Enigma_5G"
            passthrough:
              wifi-security.auth-alg: "open"
              ipv6.addr-gen-mode: "default"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "322035e3-8bac-4b5e-8a0b-d9ff4b11629d"
        name: "Enigma_5G"

My version:
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlx8416f90c89ec:
      renderer: networkd
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.5]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "Enigma_5G":
          password: "REDACTED"
      routes:
        - to: dafault
          via: 192.168.1.1

The above definitely doesn't work.  Yes, I tried rebooting, multiple times.
P.S.  I do have some knowledge of IPv4 networking, but I really have zero knowledge about either NetworkManager or networkd, so I'm really lost in the woods here.  Any help would be appreciated.
P.P.S.  It's really a darn shame that setting a static IP is easy peasey via the Ubuntu GUI-for-ignorant-people stuff if and when the adapter you're working with is a hardwired adapter, BUT sadly it seems there is no equivalent for that friendly GUI configuration stuff in the case of a WiFi adapter.  (I wanna speak to the manager! :-)

You will have to stay with IP addresses outside of the dynamic range for the subnet, you may have to use something higher than 192.168.1.199

Why would that be necessary?  I have other devices, both wired & wireless, also talking to my SOHO WiFi router and which also have been configured to use static IPs in the range of 192.168.1.0/24 and they are happily communicating with the same router all day every day.

Desktop or server???

Then again, in your file should dafault be default?

OK, so I did finally get this working, and here is the .yaml file that did it for me. network:   version: 2   renderer: networkd   wifis:     wlx8416f90c89ec:       addresses: [192.168.1.5/24]       gateway4: 192.168.1.1       nameservers:         addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]       access-points:         "Enigma_5G":           password: "REDACTED"

Well, as you can see, I can't figure out how to get the formatting right in comments. :-(

P.S. In answer to  mikewhatever this is a non-server box I'm working on.
